# Sony SDK for a6500 camera

Tags: sony-camera-api

1. Is there a SDK support for a6500 camera? I see that a6300 is supported.
2. Anyway, is it possible to set the camera timestamp programmatically(also seconds and milliseconds?). 
   Also for a6300/a6500?